# Symfony2 : Save Onetoone relation => error SQLSTATE[23000] Integrity constraint violation

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm gonna be *crazy* with saving `controller action` beetween two `entities`.

I have 2 entities:

The first one is extended FOSUser

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;    

    /**
     * @var Namespace\LoginBundle\Entity\T $t
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Namespace\LoginBundle\Entity\T", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $t;
}
```

the second one is:

```
class T 
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;   

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Namespace\LoginBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $user;
}
```

when I'm login into my application and the `User` is still saved so into my database I have a row with `T` field `null`.

Into my controller I have this method:

```
public function createAction()
    {       
        $entity  = new T();        

        // user
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $entity->setUser($user);
        $user->setT($entity);

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = $this->createForm(new TType(), $entity);        
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

            $em->persist($entity);                
            $em->persist($entity->getUser());
            $em->persist($user->getT());

            $em->flush();                               

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('t_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('NamespaceXXXXBundle:T:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()                
        ));
    }
```

I don't understand why, I have this error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`namespace`.`t`, CONSTRAINT `FK_58C6694C54EE02A4` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`))
```

Please, help me

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem with this exception

```
request.CRITICAL: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mybundle`.`File`, CONSTRAINT `FK_70684D4DA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `JEP_File` (`id`)) (uncaught exception)
```

The problem was in mapping definition. I used bad mapping in File entity. Target entity in my case was mappihg to itself - File. Thats why foreign keys didnt match inversioning table.

**bad**

```
//...
class File{

   @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File",inversedBy="files")
//...
```

**good**

```
//...
class File{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User",inversedBy="files")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $owner;
//...
```

Hope, this helps.
Try to look into dbs schema and dont forget to update it